# Get file sftp by date

Tags: powershell, scp

Any ideea how can I get file from server via sftp by last modify date? (I have this script but I don't know how to implement)

Thank you,

```
$TodaysDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%d.%m.%Y %R"

    function Read-Date {
  param(
    [String] $prompt
  )
  $result = $null
  do {
    $s = Read-Host $prompt
    if ( $s ) {
      try {
        $result = Get-Date $s
        break
      }
      catch [Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException] {
        Write-Host "Date not valid"
      }
    }
    else {
      break
    }
  }
  while ( $true )
  $result
}

Write-Host "Today's date: $TodaysDate"

$startDate = Read-Date "Enter Start Date"
$endDate = Read-Date "Enter End Date"

Get-SCPFolder -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $credentials -RemoteFolder $RemoteLogFolder -LocalFolder $LocalLogFolder -Verbose
```

Comment: You can use `LastWriteTime` to sort that download part @Bogdan

Comment: Of course @RanadipDutta but I really don't know how to implement..

Comment: So it seems you will need to learn a little bit about PowerShell so that you can adapt the code example to what you need.